# Import String and convert to JSX in Expo

Tags: react-native, svg, jsx, expo

I would like to import a file as a String.  Edit it.  Then convert it to a JSX element.
Specifically, one use-case would be to import an svg file.  Edit it so that it's compatible with React Native.  Then convert it to a JSX element that can be reused.

I can't seem to get a string from importing .svg files and I would prefer not to change it to .txt as other projects already use these files and we also need to keep things DRY.

How can I import this:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24.25" height="26.52">
  <defs>
    <style>
      .circle, .line {
        stroke: #77bc1f;
        stroke-linecap: round;
        stroke-width: 3.48px;
      }
      .circle {
        fill: none;
      }
      .line {
        fill: #9f9;
      }
    </style>
  </defs>
  <title>Logo Icon</title>
  <path class="circle" fill="none" d="m19.12166,7a10.27,10.27 0 1 1 
    -14,0"/>
  <line class="line" fill="#9f9" x1="12.06166" y1="1.74" 
    x2="12.06166" y2="14.88"/>
</svg>
```

And convert it into this:

```
  <Svg width={24.25} height={26.52}>
    <Path
      class="circle"
      fill="none"
      d="m19.12166,7a10.27,10.27 0 1 1 -14,0"
      stroke="#77bc1f"
      strokeLinecap="round"
      strokeWidth="3.48px"
    />
    <Line
      class="line"
      stroke="#77bc1f"
      strokeLinecap="round"
      strokeWidth="3.48px"
      fill="#000"
      x1="12.06166"
      y1="1.74"
      x2="12.06166"
      y2="14.88"
    />
  </Svg>
```

Dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

Great question. I never thought about with react native. I know with react you can do `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.  Please let me know if this works for you with rwact-native.
If doesn't may be try this from
https://medium.com/@remarkablemark/an-alternative-to-dangerously-set-innerhtml-64a12a7c1f96

Now to import the svg, there are multiple options to do that
Option 1. Use `react-native-remote-svg`
For example

```
import Image from 'react-native-remote-svg';

const SVGComponent = '<svg width="48px" height="1px" viewBox="0 0 48 1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><rect id="Rectangle-5" x="25" y="36" width="48" height="1"></rect></svg>';

<Image
  source={{
   uri: "data:image/svg+xml;utf8," + SVGComponent
}}/>
```

Option 2: 
Use `WebView`

```
<WebView
  source={{ html: svgstring }}
/>
```

Comment: It should. Part of react. So that's why I am hoping it should work with react-native. If it doesn't, let me know I will try out diff options, once I have access to a laptop.

Comment: Nice tool.  But this doesn't help me get at the string content.  When I import and .svg file, I have no access to its text.  To massage it into the format I require, I need to manipulate its actual characters.

Comment: Is it fixed now? Or may be set up a sample what you trying to do in https://snack.expo.io, I will take a look.

Comment: Its really simple.  I want to import an SVG file.  Massage it so that it's compatible with React Native then convert it to JSX.

Comment: I edited the original question so you'd have a better idea.  Thanks for helping me out on this.

Comment: I updated the answer. Take a look, and let me know if that solves your issue.

Comment: So I went ahead and used your previous suggestion - converting JSX to String on this suggestion.

const myImage = (
      <Image source={require("../assets/images/MetroNetLogoIcon.svg")} />
    );

    console.log("String: ", ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(myImage));

Comment: Result:
String:  <RCTImageView source="[object Object]" style="overflow:hidden" resizeMode="cover"></RCTImageView>

Comment: ExceptionsManager.js:84 Warning: <RCTImageView /> is using incorrect casing. Use PascalCase for React components, or lowercase for HTML elements.
    in RCTImageView (at Image.ios.js:104)
    in ForwardRef(Image) (at react-native-remote-svg/index.js:20)
    in MyImage (at HomeScreen.js:49)

Comment: ExceptionsManager.js:84 Warning: React does not recognize the `resizeMode` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `resizemode` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.
    in RCTImageView (at Image.ios.js:104)
    in ForwardRef(Image) (at react-native-remote-svg/index.js:20)
    in MyImage (at HomeScreen.js:49)

Comment: Warning: React does not recognize the `tintColor` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `tintcolor` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.
    in RCTImageView (at Image.ios.js:104)
    in ForwardRef(Image) (at react-native-remote-svg/index.js:20)
    in MyImage (at HomeScreen.js:49)

Comment: Also, attempting to render <Image source={require("../assets/images/MetroNetLogoIcon.svg")} /> showed nothing.

Comment: Umm did you try `react-native-remote-svg` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-remote-svg) or  `WebView` (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview)?

Comment: Just to clarify `<Image source={require("../assets/images/MetroNetLogoIcon.svg")} /> ` in this image is imported from  `react-native-remote-svg`?

Comment: Yes.  No dice.  So I created a dup of it but extensioned with .js with contents like so, [export const svg = `<svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer.....`.  Massaged it with regex and an now exploring parsing it back to JSX.